# Test file in Flutter with Android Studio IDE show nothing here

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, tdd, flutter-bloc

I am studying Flutter TDD Clean Architecture Course by Reso Coder. While writing a test file, I am unable to run it. The run icon in the test file shows 'Nothing here'. I cannot find the test file in the Run menu also. I am attaching a screenshot below. Anybody can help me. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you use Intellij or Android Studio. So you can check 2 things:

- Settings >> Languages & Framework >> Flutter : check "allow files ending with _test.dart to be recognized as tests"
- Settings >> Languages & Framework >> Dart : check "enable Dart support" and verify the path of your "Dart SDK path"